# mybb how to set default prefix for some forums adding a trigger to mybb_threads table

Tags: mysql, triggers, mybb

what i need is to add a default prefix to all new thread in one forum.

i tried to create a trigger in php admin

this is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_thread_prefix BEFORE INSERT ON mybb_threads
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.prefix=46
```

## 1142 - TRIGGER command denied to user 'xxx'@'localhost' for table 'mybb_threads'

the forum is hosted in altervista.

Comment: login as `root` and then `GRANT TRIGGER ON *.* TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` where the username and password is the one you are using to access the DB.

Comment: ok now i have the rights to create trigger, but get error in this script: DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER 'set_thread_prefix' BEFORE INSERT ON mybb_threads
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 IF NEW.fid == 46 THEN SET NEW.prefix = 2;
    ELSE IF NEW.fid == 49 THEN SET NEW.prefix = 3;
    ELSE IF NEW.fid == 54 THEN SET NEW.prefix = 4;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the trigger should look like below. You had `else if` but in mysql its `elseif` no space in between

```
delimiter //
create trigger set_thread_prefix before insert on mybb_threads
for each row
begin
 if new.fid = 46 then
   set new.prefix = 2;
 elseif new.fid = 49 then
   set new.prefix = 3;
 elseif new.fid = 54 then
  set new.prefix = 4;
 end if;
end ;//

delimiter ;
```